# How many minimal $k$-cycles can you put in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I wish to construct an unweighted, undirected graph on $n$ nodes that maximizes the number of minimal cycles of size $\ge k$.  What is known about this problem?  How many cycles can I squeeze in?

Additionally, how does the problem change if I require that my graph has $\ge m$ edges?

Clarification: I care purely about the *existence* of a many-cycled graph; it doesn't need to be efficiently constructable.

Comment: Crossposted on [mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/157277/how-many-edges-can-you-put-in-a-graph-such-that-every-edge-belongs-to-a-minimal).

Comment: By minimal cycle, do you mean the same as induced cycle?

Comment: I see there's already an answer here, which is great. However, our policy is not to allow simultaneous cross posting (you can cross post after a day or two if you're not getting the answer you want).

Comment: Apologies, I won't do it again -- thanks for filling me in.

Answer (score 2):

If $k$ is divisible by 2 we can take a clique on $n/2$ vertices and subdivide each edge once.
This graph will have ${n/2 \choose k/2} \cdot (k/2-1)!/2$ cycles of length $k$.

Hence the total number of cycles is $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=k/2}^{i=n/2} {n/2 \choose i} \cdot (i-1)!$